# Blank page in Internet Explorer when I deploy ES5 transpiled code polymer starter kit in IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-starter-kit

I have a Blank page in Internet Explorer when I deploy ES5 transpiled code polymer starter kit in IIS. I am using Polymer 2, and the latest version of Polymer Starter Kit (v3.1.0): https://github.com/polymerelements/polymer-starter-kit/releases

It works with Chrome.

I have transpiled my polymer code with different presets with polymer build (like es5-bundled, with the js compiled) , but I can´t get the page rendered.

It works when I deploy on my local full IIS, but not when I deploy on a remote server (but it works when I request the page with Chrome).

I don't know what else I can try. Thanks!

Comment: Blank page?  What about console logs?  Any errors occurring?

Comment: I have two errors when I refresh with the console opened:

SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
[IP ADDRESS] (4,48)

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
[IP ADDRESS] (7,68)